# Binding enums at the GET request by one of its values, not by its name

Tags: playframework

I have a data bean model, that contains a member that is an enum:

```
public enum Repo {
    TRUNK_SNAPSHOTS(1),
    TRUNK_RELEASES(2);

    private final int id;
    Repo(int id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
}
```

I want to call my controller, like   < url >/?repo=1, rather than repo=TRUNK_SNAPSHOTS.

Is there any way without having to write my own Formatter?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, e.g. Play doesn't know beans (that's Java EE or Spring framework).

Comment: I have an enum type as an attribute of a class inside the models package. When this class is being binded from a controller using: Form.form().bindFromRequest(), I need to provide with a way of selecting the right enum from a string coming from the GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up doing this in the Global class:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    Logger.info("Application has started");
    Formatters.register(Repo.class, new SimpleFormatter<Repo>() {   //for reading out from the url get
        @Override
        public Repo parse(String arg0, Locale arg1) throws ParseException {
            for(Repo r : Repo.values()) {
                if(arg0.equals(r.id))
                    return r;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String print(Repo arg0, Locale arg1) {
            return arg0.id;
        }
    });
}
```